# Issue when parsing JSON with nested objects using streaming parser

Tags: php, json, parsing

I'm using the following code as a base for parsing my JSON: http://soyuka.me/streaming-big-json-files-the-good-way/

It works fine for most of the JSON-data I have but once it encounters a JSON-object as a direct child to another it fails.

This is a simplified version of my JSON:

```
[
    {
        "title": "Title",
        "child_object": {
            "title": "Child Title"
        }
    },
    {
        "title": "Title 2",
        "child_object": {
            "title": "Child Title 2"
        }
    }

]
```

After being parsed I end up with this result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Title
                )

            [child_object] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Child Title 2
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Title 2
                )

        )

)
```

If I turn the child object into an array the parser will produce this result, identical to how it would have been if I'd used json_decode on the JSON-data:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Title
                    [child_object] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [child_title] => Child Title
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Title 2
                    [child_object] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [title] => Child Title 2
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Any ideas of how to get the child object in it's proper place when parsing the JSON file?

Answer (score 0):

It works like below :

```
$str = '[
    {
        "title": "Title",
        "child_object": {
            "title": "Child Title"
        }
    },
    {
        "title": "Title 2",
        "child_object": {
            "title": "Child Title 2"
        }
    }

]';

$json = json_decode($str);

foreach($json as $data) {
    echo $data->{'title'};
    echo $data->{'child_object'}->{'title'};
}
```

Comment: The real JSON-file I use is too big for json_deocde as it runs out of memory, otherwise I would use it.